# Is it possible to create an orchard autoroute using contents of a custom type property?

Tags: c#-4.0, orchardcms, routes, permalinks

I have an Orchard cms module with some additional Content types set up and have added an AutoRoute component via code.
Everything works perfectly, however I am not happy with the default permalink pattern.

What I am trying to do is add a custom pattern and use one of the public properties in my content type.  In my case the custom type has a public property called ClubName and I would like that to be used (It makes more sense from a routing perspective).
The Orchard part class name is called `TrackPart`.

I have tried `{Content.TrackPart.ClubName}`, `{Content.Track.ClubName}`, `{ContentItem.TrackPart.ClubName}`,`{Content.TrackPart.ClubName}` and various other variations but nothing seems to be working.

I am really new to Orchard so there is a high chance I am missing something simple.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In response to feedback from @Bertrand-le-roy I created my own token by copying an example token.  I can now get see the token in the drop down menu and select it.  However the route pattern is still not working.

I can only assume that I have misunderstood the Evaluate() function's `context.For` usage.  It looks like I am not getting the data I need

Here is what I have so far.

`public class TrackPartTokens : ITokenProvider {
        private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;`

```
    public TrackPartTokens(IContentManager contentManager) {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public void Describe(dynamic context) {
        context.For("Track", T("Track"), T("Tokens for Track"))
            .Token("ClubName", T("ClubName"), T("The name of the club."))
            ;
    }

    public void Evaluate(dynamic context) {
        context.For<TrackPart>("Track")
            .Token("ClubName", (Func<TrackPart, object>)(field => field.ClubName))
            .Chain("ClubName", "ClubName", (Func<TrackPart, object>)(field =>field.ClubName))
            ;
    }</code>
```

The above code was based on the DateTimeField token inside the Orchard.Fields module.

context.For("DateTimeField")
                .Token("Date", (Func)(field => field.DateTime))
                .Chain("Date", "Date", (Func)(field => field.DateTime));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make your own token. It's really easy. Copy a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  This framework is amazing!  I took your advice and made my own token and it appears in the route menu without a problem.  However the route is still not being generated with the correct information.  I think it has something to do with the last line of the Evaluate() function.  I am not sure whether I am actually getting the data to generate the route.

Comment: Yes, this may depend when the autoroute gets do do its work. I'm not sure how to ensure the order in which things happen. I'll ask around.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

After some troubleshooting I managed to get the autoroute working by changing my implementaion to the following (adapted to your example, note that your setup might require some changes to the linq-function):

In your tokens-class:

- First add a using System.Linq statement.
- Then change your Evaluate implementation to the following:

  ```
  context.For<IContent>("Content")
         .Token("ClubName", (Func<IContent>, object>)(content => 
              content.ContentItem.Parts.OfType<TrackPart>().First().ClubName));
  ```
- Make sure your AutoroutePart settings in Migrations.cs uses the Content-prefix. Like:

  ```
  .WithPart("AutoroutePart", partBuilder =>
      partBuilder
      .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "true")
      .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "false")
      .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions",
      @"[{Name:'Track', Pattern:'{Content.ClubName}', 
          Description:'Your description'}]")
      .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex", "0"))
  ```

There seems to be some problems with the TokenManager-class in Orchard source that only allows the target-parameter to equal "Content" in order for the call: _data.TryGetValue(target, out value) to work (TokenManager.cs, line 67). I have tried a number of different setups but the _data-dictionary always only contain the "Content" key.

Comment: The `Token()` call within the *Evaluate* implementation can be shorten to `.Token("ClubName", content => content.As<TrackPart>().ClubName);`. No `System.Linq` is necessary.

Comment: The "_data-dictionary" only contains the "Content" key due to the method which supplies the dictionary object: `private IDictionary<string, object> BuildTokenContext(IContent item) { return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Content", item } }; }` (which returns a Dictionary with only 1 item in it with the key "Content") in **Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Autoroute\Services\AutorouteService.cs line 77**. So, in order for your tokens to work, they must be  selected from the category "Content Items" in the token drop down list. This explains why you have to create your tokens under that category.