# Autoroute URL patterns containing custom tokens

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm having trouble getting my custom tokens to work with my ContentPart. My problem is the same as what is described here:
[Is it possible to create an orchard autoroute using contents of a custom type property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716230/is-it-possible-to-create-an-orchard-autoroute-using-contents-of-a-custom-type-pr)

I have created my tokens:

```
namespace MyNS.Types.Providers
{
    public class BioPartTokens : ITokenProvider
    {
        public BioPartTokens() {
            T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        }
        public Localizer T { get; set; }
        public void Describe(dynamic context) {
            context.For("Bio", T("Bio"), T("Tokens for the Bio content type"))
                .Token("FirstName", T("FirstName"), T("First name of person."))
                .Token("LastName", T("LastName"), T("Last name of person."));
        }

        public void Evaluate(dynamic context) {
            context.For<BioPart>("Bio")
                .Token("FirstName", (Func<BioPart, object>) (f => f.ContentItem.Parts.OfType<BioPart>().First().FirstName.ToLower()))
                .Chain("FirstName", "FirstName", (Func<BioPart, object>)(f => f.ContentItem.Parts.OfType<BioPart>().First().FirstName.ToLower()))
                .Token("LastName", (Func<BioPart, object>)(f => f.ContentItem.Parts.OfType<BioPart>().First().LastName.ToLower()))
                .Chain("LastName", "LastName", (Func<BioPart, object>)(f => f.ContentItem.Parts.OfType<BioPart>().First().LastName.ToLower()))
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
namespace MyNS.Types.Models
{
    public class BioPart: ContentPart<BioPartRecord>
    {
        public string FirstName {
            get { return Record.FirstName; }
            set { Record.FirstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return Record.LastName; }
            set { Record.LastName = value; }
        }

        public RoleInSchool RoleInSchool
        {
            get { return Record.RoleInSchool; }
            set { Record.RoleInSchool = value; }
        }

        public bool IsBlogger {
            get { return Record.IsBlogger; }
            set { Record.IsBlogger = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Though I've tried URL patterns with all of the following tokens, I've not been able to get a value back from the form that I've submitted:

```
{Content.Bio.FirstName}
{Content.BioPart.FirstName}
{Bio.FirstName}
{BioPart.FirstName}
```

No errors are being logged.

Comment: It's possible but you probably have timing problems there.

Comment: Any hints on how to win the race?

Comment: First, verify that this is the issue, by putting breakpoints in your driver's update method, as well as in your tokens and in the autoroute part's driver. Then, try to play with dependency order in your manifest.